# Problem calculating problems with trigonometric functions in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

im developing a program that is gonna print the results of a formula that requires to give it three data to get the results, so the problem is about "working using", i don't really want to change the code (to make it more simple, because i know that it can be more simply) but when i try to make the math, something is wrong, the problem gets of the user the force applicated in newtons, displacement and angle, i don't know what i am calculating wrong, this is the code:
if the user gives 20 newtons, 8m of displacement and 60º of angle the programs must to print the result as: 80 J.

im using Xcode, and it mus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxTP0.png)

`code`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g3OZ.png)

I'll be very grateful if somebody help me, thx!

Comment: Please don't post code or other text in images. Copy-paste into the question body instead. See [ask]. Please edit your question accordingly. Also, it is not clear what "_something is wrong,_" is supposed to mean. What happens instead of the expected output?

Comment: You should be aware that trig functions in C++ operate in _radians_, not degrees.  A conversion is required.  As for your use of the actual symbol for _pi_ as a variable name, or any non-ASCII character (including your _delta-x_) is 100% inappropriate, even if it compiles.  Don't do that.  Use variable names like `pi` and `dx`.

Comment: srry, i dont know why i cant insert the code, it says that doesnt have the format of code, and, i already change π for pi, but still print the same output.